# How to reload a relationship on an existing parse object

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a bunch of objects from a PFFetch in an array. Those objects have links (pointer array <-> pointer) to other object. To limit the amount of data sent for my initial fetch I don't want to download all of the linked objects using includeKey on the fetch.

Sometime later, I have a subset of these objects and I do want to fetch the related objects and relations of those objects. If I fetch them again, I duplicate the objects in my app (and presumably needlessly send objects over the wire that I already have in my app)

I.e. I would like some of my objects in my original array to appear as if the original fetch had:

```
[query includeKey:@"relationship"];
[query includeKey@"relationship.secondRelationship"];
```

set on the original key. What is the best way to do this? I had imagined some API on PFObject like:

```
+(void) fetchIfNeededInBackground:(NSArray*)objects includeKey:(NSString*)key block:...
```

or

```
- (void)includeKeyAtNextFetch:(NSString*)key
```

But I can't find anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's POSSIBLE you're after the famous **containedIn** query..

here's an example of using containedIn to address the famous problem "match friends from FB"....

```
+(void)findFBFriendsWhoAreOnSkywall
{
// issue a fb graph api request to get the fbFriend list...

[APP huddie];

[FBRequestConnection
 startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(
  FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
  {
  if (!error)
   {
   // here, the result will contain an array of the user's
   // FB friends, with, the facebook-id in the "data" key

   NSArray *fbfriendObjects = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

   int kountFBFriends = fbfriendObjects.count;

   NSLog(@"myfriends result; count: %d", kountFBFriends);

   // NOW MAKE A SIMPLE ARRAY of the fbId of the friends
   // NOW MAKE A SIMPLE ARRAY of the fbId of the friends
   // NOW MAKE A SIMPLE ARRAY of the fbId of the friends

   NSMutableArray *fbfriendIds =
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:kountFBFriends];
   for (NSDictionary *onFBFriendObject in fbfriendObjects)
    [fbfriendIds addObject:[onFBFriendObject objectForKey:@"id"]];

   for (NSString *onef in fbfriendIds)
      NSLog(@"and here they are .. %@", onef);

   // query to find friends whose facebook ids are in that list:
   // USE THAT SIMPLE ARRAY WITH THE MAGIC 'containedIn' call...

   // amazingly easy using the ever-loved containedIn:
   // amazingly easy using the ever-loved containedIn:
   // amazingly easy using the ever-loved containedIn:

   PFQuery *SWUSERSTOADDASFRIENDS = [PFUser query];
   [SWUSERSTOADDASFRIENDS whereKey:@"fbId" containedIn:fbfriendIds];
   [SWUSERSTOADDASFRIENDS findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^
    (NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
    if (error) // problem getting the matching-friends list
     {
     [PFAnalytics .. it al went to hell.];
     NSLog(@"disaster at the last step!  but that's ok");

     [APP.hud hide:YES];
     [backTo literallyGoToMainPage];
     }
    else
     {
     // so all the people in OBJECTS, now make them in to SW friends.

     [PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"FBMatchDone" ...];
     NSLog(@"found this many fb matches ... %d", objects.count);
     [FBMatch actuallyMakeThemFriends:objects];
     [APP.hud hide:YES];
     [FBMatch message .. objects.count showTheseNames:objects];
     }
    }];
   }
  else // problem getting the friend list....
   {
   [PFAnalytics .. problem];

   [APP.hud hide:YES];
   [backTo literallyGoToMainPage];
   }
  }];
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. For the time being I've worked around the problem by aggressive use of includeKey: in my initial query. When I come back and optimise I'll be sure to try this.

Comment: I was thinking.......... I doubt there'd be any problem just always "includeKey" ... I mean even for 1000s of records it's a very small amount of data.  I know, we've never bothered "delaying the include" even when the "include" is only used on a handful out of 1000s of results.  Maybe it's not a big problem....

Comment: Generally "containedIn" is incredibly useful (as in the example)